# Count the number of documents with mongoose (then also use that info)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

So Ive seen a lot of similar questions about counting database entries and I have figured out how to use callback functions to console.log the number, but because of the local scope of that callback I cant figure out how to actually USE that number in another function. I would like to make a random number generator for between 0 and the number of documents in my database. This is what I have so far.

```
 Comic.countDocuments({}, function (err, count) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log(count)
    }
});
```

I would love for it to work like this but it doesnt. Whenever I do it num ends up being a huge amount of metadata instead of a number. Any ideas?

```
 let num = Comic.countDocuments({}, function (err, count) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        return count
    }
});

console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * num))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to return data from `async` function, because it's async in nature. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/7482427) on SO to better understand how async calls work.

But you can simply it a bit by using `async/await`

```
const randomFunction = async() => 
{
  let num = await Comic.countDocuments({});
  console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * num));
}
```

Then you can call `randomFunction();` wherever you want (as long as it's exported, if using in separate file).

This will `console.log` the random number